# transferring oneD array into 2D array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, console-application

i searched for my problem but i become hopeless , i want to transfer the values of a one dimension array into a two dimension array by taking a note that i want a general solution (not knowing the length of the array) also i don't want to use a ready function like `Array.copy` . 
PS : the length will be determined by the user but it has to be a square matrix .
here's my code for transferring a twoD Array into 1D Array but i got stuck with doing the opposite :

```
Public Sub TransferTo1D(ByRef B(,) As Integer)
   Dim ARR1D(B.Length - 1) As Integer, e As Integer = 0
    For i = 0 To B.GetUpperBound(0)
        For j = 0 To B.GetUpperBound(1)
            ARR1D(e) = B(i, j)
            e += 1
        Next
    Next
End Sube
```

thanks for your help<3

Comment: what should the form of the target array be? should it be of a fixed size or dependant of the source array? fo dependant od the source, should it be a square matrix or domething other. Please specify your question a bit more clear.

Comment: oh i'm sorry that's my first question i'll edit it , it's a square matrix and depends on the source like the user will determine the length of the array but it has to be a square matrix because it's easier for me to begin with. @Detonar

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you. Pick up a pen and paper and write down what the logic should be, then write code to implement that logic. Don't try to pluck code out of the air without knowing exactly what it has to do. If you have trouble with the implementation then we can help you fix your code if you show it to us. It's not for us to work out the logic for you though.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i'm sorry if my question turned that way  but you could've been less harsh with your comment .i didn't attend for you to write the whole code like i said i want the opposite of the code in the question , i just have a problem with transferring the values in the right order because the difference in the dimensions

Comment: @katy - Edit your question to add more code to it - please don't put code like that in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution.

```
Public Function TransferTo2D(ByRef inArray() As Integer) As Integer(,)
    Dim dimSize as Integer

    'Size of one dimention of outArray needs to be the square root of inArray's size
    dimSize = Math.Sqrt(inArray.length)

    'If inArray isn't convertable to a square matrix build a square matrix that is just big enough to hold inArray's values
    While (dimSize*dimSize) < inArray.length
        dimSize = dimSize + 1

    End While

    Dim outArray(dimSize, dimSize) As Integer
    Dim counter as Integer

    counter = 0;

    'Brainless copying
    For i = 0 To dimSize - 1
        For j = 0 To dimSize - 1
            If counter < inArray.length Then ' If inArray still has values
                outArray(i, j) = inArray(counter)
                counter = counter + 1

            Else ' If inArray is out of values and outArray isn't already filled
                outArray(i, j) = 0

            End If
        Next

    Next

    Return outArray

End Function
```

First the squareroot of `inArray.length` is calculated and assigned to `dimSize`. After that `dimSize` is increased until it is big enough to hold inArray(inArray might not have a count with natural square root). After that we simply copy line by line into the new array with size `(dimArray, dimArray)`.

Comment: thanks a lot i really appreciate it . i thought of declaring a variable to count the length but didn't know how .thanks again i really think it's correct but i have to copy it and write a lot of processes with it to read an array from a text file and sort it to write it in another text file @denotar